# What voltage can a 4mm LED light handle if I'm directly wiring to the power source?

Tags: led

I have a toggle switch that I want to wire but it has an LED in it. I want to know what the voltage requirement is so that I don't blow the LED.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the part? For this to make sense, there's *probably* a current limiting resistor included in the part --- but only the datasheet can tell you what voltages it's designed for.

Comment: If you don't have a datasheet, it's best to start low and slowly power it. limit the current to about 5-10mA using a resistor and the voltage to 2V and look at the luminosity.

Comment: It's probably a 3 pin led toggle switch, and while most are 12v targeted (auto applications), that's just an assumption. It should either say on the switch itself, or the part number might bring up a datasheet, but that's not likely if it's some no name after-market car modding part.

Answer (score 3):

The short (but unhelpful) answer is this: "There isn't one!"

Let me explain.

First of all, the brightness of a diode is approximately proportional to the current flowing through it.  If there's insufficient current, the LED won't be bright enough for you to see.  On the other hand, if there's too much current, the LED could be too bright, or worse!

The 'or worse' is that you could "blow out" the LED.  The main factor at work here is power: If the power is too high, for too long a time, the LED will fail.  In electronics, power is current times voltage, or P = I*V.

Your power supply determines the voltage across your LED, but what determines the current?  Well, LEDs are a type of diode, which approximately obey the [Shockley Diode Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Shockley_diode_equation).  This is different from resistors, which are [Ohmic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law). What this means in practice is that any variation in the applied voltage causes an exponential change in the current through the device, and that's *very* important.

Here's another thing you need to know: In any manufactured object, there's always some variation from piece to piece.  If you click on the first link, you'll see that the diode equation depends on something called n, which is the "ideality factor."  In a batch of diodes, n is going to vary a little from piece to piece.  But, the current through the diode depends exponentially on the ratio of Vd (your power supply voltage) to n*Vt (the ideality factor times the thermal voltage)!

That thermal voltage is important, too!  As the diode heats up, the current flowing through it will increase.  That increases the power dissipated by your diode, which makes it even hotter!

The practical take-away from the above two paragraphs is that you can't just specify a single voltage for a particular type of LED and connect it to a power supply.  Even if you get lucky and don't have thermal runaway when the diode is first connected, any change in temperature will cause the brightness to change.  Also, substituting one LED for another will almost certainly cause problems.

So you need to have some way to limit the current through the diode.  There are any number of ways to do this: A constant current power supply (easy to buy or build with a few transistors and passives) or a current-limiting resistor are the two most common.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to connect a LED (or any diode for that matter), to a source since you have no control over the current.

Besides that, datasheets are your friend.
Your LED is probably similar to the one described [here (Warning: PDF Auto Download)](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-1136EN)

What is important in that document?
Peak Forward Current: 100 mA (don't pass this, or you will burn your LED)
Reverse Voltage: 5V (don't apply more than 5V in reverse direction or "")
Forward Voltage (typical): 2.1V (answers your question)
At that voltage, the LED's current is 20mA (again, according to datasheet)

But it's MUCH better to use a current limiting resistor in series with your LED.

For example with a 5V source, where 2.1V @ 20 mA is assigned to the LED, you have 3.9V left
to use on the resistor. You pick the value of the resistor by the amount of current you need, in this case 20 mA.

$$V = R I \Rightarrow R = \frac{3.9}{0.02} = 195 Ω $$

A common resistor value close enough that you can buy at any shop would be 180Ω. Notice, that the maximum current in the resulting circuit would be 5V / 180Ω = 27.7 mA, well in the range of the LED capacity.